# CSS styling - title color on mouse hover

Tags: css, joomla, hover, styling, joomla-extensions

Someone can help me with this css code for Joomla 2.5 extension - RSS news title slider.

It has very poor css styling -

```
#RSS-SHOW-SETTING1 p {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    }
```

which displays me titles which are white on mouse hover (on white background make it invisible on hover). So I need to put a parameter into this css id selector which change color of hovering title to green (or any other color). I can not handle it with my modest css knowledge.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing your default `p` tags are set to white so you could do:

```
#RSS-SHOW-SETTING1 p:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Similar answer as this one from Petr Vocelka, please write me how to combine it with my existing source code.

Comment: You don't need to combine it, just insert it on a new line. Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to be of service, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is by placing the following css code:

```
#RSS-SHOW-SETTING1 p {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried, not working, probably because these parameters are related to whole <div id="#RSS-SHOW-SETTINGS1"> ... </div>. But nothing changes with adding this line..Appreciate your try

Comment: The div is <div id="#RSS-SHOW-SETTINGS1"> ??
I have never seen # these characters being used in html...

Comment: My mistake, <div id="RSS-SHOW-SETTING1">... I found solution and mark it with a check..Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by adding this piece of code to your styles:

```
#RSS-SHOW-SETTING1 p:hover {
    color: green !important;
}
```

It change color to green, when mouse cursor hover the title.

Comment: Ok this looks like might work but how should I implement this yours lines of code with my existing.. LIke this: 'code' #RSS-SHOW-SETTING1 p {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    } 'code' and behind it your part 'code' #RSS-SHOW-SETTING1 p:hover {
    color: green !important;
} 'code' or I should combine it someway...?

Comment: I made a mistake with the code tag and type again - Ok this looks like might work but how should I implement this yours lines of code with my existing.. LIke this: <code> #RSS-SHOW-SETTING1 p { width:100%; vertical-align:middle; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px; } </code> and behind it your part <code> #RSS-SHOW-SETTING1 p:hover { color: green !important; } </code> or I should combine it someway...?

Comment: Take your lines of code and under them paste mine. But as I can see, you solved it. Happy future coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Please update html and css so tha it work in all browser like this

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
#RSS-SHOW-SETTING1 a:hover {
color: green !important;
}
</style>

<div id="RSS-SHOW-SETTING1">
<p>
<a href="#">Testing by admin</a>
</p>
</div>
</html>
```

if you use #RSS-SHOW-SETTING1 p:hover then it create problem in IE browser